# Why does transforming PDF pages drop embedded fonts?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I maintain a program which resizes PDF pages which are larger than DIN A4.

This program uses PDFBox v3 (3.0.0 when I discovered the bug, an update to 3.0.2 did not help).

When resizing a page, PDFs with embedded fonts become unreadable. It seems that the transformation via the following code results in embedded fonts being dropped.

```
public void scale(PDDocument pdf, PDPage page) throws IOException {
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdf, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false);
    contentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(factor, factor));
    contentStream.close();
    page.setMediaBox(targetMediaBox);
}
```

The input PDF has 3 Windows-related fonts, embedded as *subsets*.

When I replace this method with an empty implementation, then the output PDF still holds the original, embedded fonts.

Why does the transformation drop the fonts?

Comment: Please share a PDF that shows the effect.

Comment: The original can't be published for privacy reasons. I tried to create a test document with Word, using Arial and Segoue UI. Both were embedded by Word into the generated PDF. Sadly, this file is completely fine being transformed into a smaller size, the embedded fonts are still present... I don't know what characteristics a PDF could have to cause the fonts to be dropped.

Comment: Open the file with PDFDebugger and find out where the fonts are. Then do the same with the modified file. Look if you see something different. Also watch for log messages.

Comment: Also try to use PDFBox 2 (current version is 2.0.30). If the code works with PDFBox 2, this may indicate that the issue still is some bug in the PDFBox 3 changes. If it does not work with PDFBox 2, it is very likely that it's an issue of your PDF. Ah, another question, have you tested the file with only one PDF viewer or with multiple ones? If only one, which one? And please also check with others.